# Form Hide() then Show() always rerendering contents

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a sample code to create a form with a label with text and a small image.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$label = [Windows.Forms.Label]@{
    Image  = $image
    Height = $image.Height
    Text   = 'Sample text.'
}
$form = [Windows.Forms.Form]@{
    ControlBox      = $false
    AutoSizeMode    = "GrowAndShrink"
    AutoSize        = $true
    FormBorderStyle = "fixedDialog"
    AutoScaleMode   = "dpi"
    StartPosition   = "centerScreen"
}
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Show()
```

The form was shown but the content of `$label` was loaded slower with a white background color. I tried to `Hide()` then `Show()` the form and saw it reload the content of `$label` every time.

Please advise me how I can make the content of `$label` loaded already when I `Show()` the form so I will not see the content loading with a white background every time.

Comment: `Show()` -> `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers `.show()` will show the form without hang the process to waiting for return value when form's buttons is pressed.

Comment: As far as I can determine everything is loaded in order but your `label Image` (which is not defined in the example) is in front of the `label Text`. I guess you actually want to use the `label BackgroundImage` property to put an image behind your `label Text`.

Comment: I also tried the `Label` with `BackgroundImage`. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the issue but following your description, I would tackle this as follows:
First place the your `$form` outside the screen's boundary. This will cause the form to be 'invisible' but all events related to the rendering to work as if it was shown on the screen.  Than find a event that comes after the concerned items are loaded. I think the event you are looking for is: `$form.Activated` but you might also consider to first focus your label `$form.Add_Activated({$label.focus})` and then use e.g. the `validated` event of the `$label` (`$label.Add_Validated({...})`).
Anyway, upon this event, center your form back on the screen. I am quiet sure that *moving* your form will not completely re-rendered it as happens with `hide()` - `show()` methods:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$label = [Windows.Forms.Label]@{
    Text   = 'Sample text.'
}
$form = [Windows.Forms.Form]@{
    ControlBox      = $false
    AutoSizeMode    = "GrowAndShrink"
    AutoSize        = $true
    FormBorderStyle = "fixedDialog"
    AutoScaleMode   = "dpi"
    StartPosition   = "manual"
    Left            = -9999
    Top             = -9999
}
$form.Add_Activated({
    $Screen = [Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    $Form.Left = ($Screen.Width  - $Form.Width)  / 2
    $Form.Top  = ($Screen.Height - $Form.Height) / 2
})
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Show()
```

Comment: Big thanks to @iRon
I'm looking for an event trigger like this one :D